# Is models in my django applications correctly defined?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm learning Django and created a University application in django project. Now I want to know whether the relationships defined in my models.py is correct or not?

I want to 2 things here. Firstly, I want to know the many to many relationship defined here is correct or not?. Secondly, Foreign key between students and university is correct or not?

```
from django.db import models


class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    courses = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self): return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    roll_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, primary_key=True)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Classes, blank=True, related_name="classes")

    def __str__(self): return self.name


class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attendee = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True, related_name="students")

    def __str__(self): return self.name
```

Comment: They seem okay - is there something in particular that doesn't work, or you're concerned about?

Comment: Ya,  I want to 2 things here. Firstly, I want to know the many to many relationship defined here is correct or not?. Secondly, Foreign key between students and university is correct or not?

Comment: Amanda, check my answer below. You don't need to specify the Many to Many relationship in both Classes and Students. It's redundant. You can make a call to them through the other class.

Comment: @ChrisWendel Thanks, but when actually should I use Many to Many relationship, I really need to clear this for my upcoming interview. Please help. Should I just define many to many in one of the models? i.e Classes

Comment: Yes exactly. You only need to define it in one model. I’ll explain in my answer below

Comment: Amanda, if the below answer is correct then please go ahead and check the green checkmark. Otherwise I may need help understanding what you are asking.

Comment: @ChrisWendel done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do a Many to Many in both `Classes` and `Students`. Django will actually make this connection for you and you will be able to call classes from students or vice versa. Look below in this link and scroll down to "sets" it explains what I am referring to.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/

You only need many to many in one model because you can access the relationship both ways. So for example, if you are trying to see which students a class has and the many to many was on the student class you would query with the Student model and filter by Class. If you were trying to see which classes a student has you would need to use a prefetch_related query on the Class_set. I suggest you read about sets, prefetch_related, and select_related. These are important in Django. Django docs are a very good resource!

Good luck with your interview!

Sorry for the formatting, I am on my phone.